# How to move/resize sashes of Sash forms using arrow buttons (or anything like button) on divider line?

Tags: java, forms, resize, swt, divider

In my RCP application, I'm using Horizontal `SashForm`s. Sash can be moved using divider line. But I need my sashes to be moved using buttons (left/right) on divider line.

How can I create Sash form having buttons on divider line to move sashes to left or right up to specific width? I searched on internet, but did not find any relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Expected behavior is not posible directly, as SashForm does not have such property. But it can be posible using our own CustomSashForm.

Please have look at below URL, they have written their own SashForm to achieve the requirement, this has solved my problem:

http://svn.bonitasoft.org/bonita-studio/tags/bonita-studio-5.8/plugins/org.bonitasoft.studio.groovy.ui/src/org/bonitasoft/studio/groovy/ui/dialog/BonitaSashForm.java

Thank You for the all the replies. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will shift the sash to the left or the right by approximately 1px each time you click on the according button.

```
private static int middle = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    final Button left = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
    final Button right = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);

    left.setText("Left");
    right.setText("Right");

    Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if(event.widget.equals(left))
                middle++;
            else
                middle--;

            int[] weights = new int[]{1, 1};

            int width = form.getClientArea().width;

            weights[0] = (int)Math.round(width / 2f + middle);
            weights[1] = (int)Math.round(width / 2f - middle);

            form.setWeights(weights);
        }
    };

    left.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
    right.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);

    form.setWeights(new int[] { 1, 1 });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Click ten times on the left button and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.. Above code creates buttons in sash areas, however I need buttons to be shown on divider line(to be part of divider line).

Comment: @Pooja Well, at least not with a `SashForm`. Do you need to be able to resize it by dragging as well or do you just want to change things with the buttons?

Comment: It should be resizable by dragging as well. and in addition it should show arrows on divider line, so that after clicking on it, sash will resize to specific/intended width. I would have shown you screnshot, but I'm not able to upload image here..:(